# How to UPDATE all rows in SQL with one query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an existing DATABASE of Prestashop, and I have made small modifications to it. I made a separate PHP page which gets data from table with products (only the data i need) and shows me all products that ARE IN THAT TABLE, one after another. I also have a function which updates a products, on which i press EDIT.

So, in a simple words i can update a single product per click. But now I have about 220 products, and in order to update a value (price) for each product, now, i must click EDIT for each product, 220 times.

Is there a way to make a query in order to update all rows after i click a BUTTON?

**Bellow I will show you some basic parts from my script:**

***GET function:***

```
<?php

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ps_product";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");

while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
?>
<!-- HTML CODE -->
<? } ?>
```

***UPDATE function for each product***

```
if($_POST["hdnCmd"] == "Update")
{
    $strSQL = "UPDATE ps_product_shop SET ";
    $strSQL .="id_product = '".$_POST["txtEditid_product"]."' ";
    $strSQL .=",price = '".$_POST["txtEditprice"]."' ";
    $strSQL .=",active = '".$_POST["txtEditactive"]."' ";
    $strSQL .="WHERE id_product = '".$_POST["hdnEditid_product"]."' ";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    if(!$objQuery)
    {
        echo "Error Update [".mysql_error()."]";
    }

}
```

**$_POST["hdnEditid_product]** is the product id value that is taken from table.

---

**Please help me to understand how to make a similar *****UPDATE function***** **which will update all rows (product_id) at once?**

As an example i must work around this code:

```
if($_POST["UPDATEALLPRODUCTS"] == "Update")
{
    $strSQL = "UPDATE ps_product_shop SET ";
    $strSQL .=",price = '".$_POST["txtEditprice"]."' ";
    $strSQL .="WHERE id_product = '".$_POST["hdnEditid_product"]."' ";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    if(!$objQuery)
    {
        echo "Error Update [".mysql_error()."]";
    }
}
```

but what I must add/change here:

```
$strSQL .="WHERE id_product = '".$_POST["hdnEditid_product"]."' ";
```

Comment: EACH product has different Price value!

Comment: why not you are calling any jQuery/ajax script by calling the script to update it corresponding record on loosing the focus from pricebox.rather than just clicking the update after filling the recoed. it would make easier for you

Comment: and you want to update all row's **price** ?

Comment: yes... I would love to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this ?

Make an array like this : **id => price**,  and then :

```
        $prices = array(
            1=>300,
            5=>180,
            ...
        );
        foreach ($prices as $id => $price) {
            $query = "UPDATE ps_product_shop SET price='".$price."' WHERE 
            id_product='".$id."' ";
            mysql_query($query);
        }
```

Comment: Can you make this array ?

Comment: i think your answere is pure! But i will try to make some changes to it. I mean I want the id and values to be generated based on the old value from DATABASE....

Answer (score 2):

To update all rows to the same value run this query

```
UPDATE ps_product_shop SET price='".$_POST["txtEditprice"]."';
```

NOTE: Every records in `ps_products_shop` will get the same value in price.

Comment: Thanx for your replay! BUT i guess your answere is global. In my case each porduct has different price, how will the query know product ID and its price?

Comment: Wait, you mean that you want to change the values in the input field and then run a updatequery on all rows per id? Then this is a php issue not MySQL

Comment: values are Updating on my front end by a different php script. This works perffect now. it's a math calculation and it changes the price values fro every porduct. this value is in every porduct field.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, if you insist on using a single query:

```
<?php
    $product_updates = array("1" => "500", "2" => "1299.99");
    $sql_query = "UPDATE my_database.products SET price = CASE id ";
    foreach ($product_updates as $key => $value) {
        $sql_query .= "WHEN '$key' THEN '$value' ";
    }
    $sql_query .= "END;";
    mysql_query($sql_query);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the page already has the updated price / info that you need and therefore it is just plucking the php variables out

```
UPDATE ps_product_shop SET price
 = CASE 
 WHEN id_product= $id_product_1
 THEN '$edited_price_1'
 WHEN id_product = $id_product_2
 THEN '$edited_price_2'
```

Without seeing the form structure it is hard to see what would be the correct variable names but hopefully you can take the code and go with it, i have to do something similar and have PhP autobuild the query using this method